# Laravel Test Json

Tags: laravel, json, test

Antes que nada gracias por la ayuda. Estoy implementando pruebas a un proyecto laravel 8, sin embargo al realizar la implementación idéntica a la que da laravel en su documentación me marca los siguientes errores, si alguien me pudiera orientar le agradeceria.

Estoy tratando de replicar la documentación de laravel
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#fluent-json-testing

```
use Illuminate\Testing\Fluent\AssertableJson;    

/** @test */
public function it_successfully_returns_an_existing_type_truck()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    $user = User::factory()->create();
    $typeTruck = TypeTruck::factory()->create();

    $response = $this
        ->actingAs($user)
        ->json('GET', "/types_trucks/$typeTruck->id");

    $response->assertOk();
    $response->assertJson(fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
        $json->where('id', $typeTruck->id)
             ->where('name', $typeTruck->name)
             ->etc()
        );

}
```

El error que me marca al correr mi test.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '$json' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')' in /home/garenas/Developer/www/stvamm/tests/Feature/TypeTruckTest.php:28
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/garenas/Developer/www/stvamm/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/FileLoader.php(49): PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::load('/home/garenas/D...')
> #1 /home/garenas/Developer/www/stvamm/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(402): PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::checkAndLoad('/home/garenas/D...')
> #2 /home/garenas/Developer/www/stvamm/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(530): PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->addTestFile('/home/garenas/D...')
> #3 /home/garenas/Developer/www/stvamm/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestSuiteMapper.php(67): PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->addTestFiles(Array)
> #4 /home/garenas/Developer/www/stvamm/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(390): PHPUnit\TextUI\TestSuiteMapper->map(Object(PHPUnit\TextUI\XmlConfiguration\TestSuiteCollection), '')
> #5 /home/garenas/Developer/www/stvamm/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src in /home/garenas/Developer/www/stvamm/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php on li

Comment: Que version de php tienes? Ya que la [funcion flecha](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arrow.php) (`fn() =>`) esta desde php 7.4. Asi que tienes que utilizar lo tradicional `function () { ... }`

Comment: Déjame realizar la prueba por que tengo "PHP 7.3.27"...